# Adding robust standard errors to stargazer table in R

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm using stargazer to make a hierarchical regression table with 8 progressively larger OLS regression models, and I would like it to display heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors instead of traditional SEs.

I've used the `vcov` function from the sandwich package to obtain robust standard errors and compiled them into a list, like so:

```
library(sandwich)
cov1 <- vcovHC(ols1, type = "HC")
cov2 <- vcovHC(ols2, type = "HC")
cov3 <- vcovHC(ols3, type = "HC")
cov4 <- vcovHC(ols4, type = "HC")
cov5 <- vcovHC(ols5, type = "HC")
cov6 <- vcovHC(ols6, type = "HC")
cov7 <- vcovHC(ols7, type = "HC")
cov8 <- vcovHC(ols8, type = "HC")
robust.se1 <- sqrt(diag(cov1))
robust.se2 <- sqrt(diag(cov2))
robust.se3 <- sqrt(diag(cov3))
robust.se4 <- sqrt(diag(cov4))
robust.se5 <- sqrt(diag(cov5))
robust.se6 <- sqrt(diag(cov6))
robust.se7 <- sqrt(diag(cov7))
robust.se8 <- sqrt(diag(cov8))

list_robust.se <- c(robust.se1, robust.se2, robust.se3, robust.se4, robust.se5, robust.se6, robust.se7, robust.se8)
```

And then I added `se = list(list_robust.se)` to the stargazer command. I can see that the standard errors in the table *did* change, but the displayed standard errors are not the same values I get when I just print the robust SE vectors. For example:

```
print(robust.se1)
(Intercept) elasticity_10 
0.95301787    0.09344417
```

The standard error in the table, however, are 1.129 and 0.071:

```
Regression Results
==============================================
                         Dependent variable:  
                       -----------------------
                       (Log) Events per capita
----------------------------------------------
Elasticity Score (x10)          0.157         
                               (0.071)        
Intercept                     -11.946        
                               (1.129)        
----------------------------------------------
Observations                     435          
R2                              0.014         
Adjusted R2                     0.011         
==============================================
```

Why are they different?

Guessing the values in the table are the correct ones because they make more sense, but would like to know for certain.